# Вывести число с помощью рекурсии

Tags: рекурсия, c, c++, visual-studio

Ребят, помогите, пожалуйста. Учим рекурсию в универе). Нужно написать программу, печатающую десятичную запись введенного натурального числа, используя только операции печати цифр от 0 до 9. Думал получить первое число, вывести его, потом удалить из числа и снова в эту функцию, но никак не получается..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вариант попроще, чем предложил [@DreamChild](/users/10162/dreamchild).

```
void print_num(uint32_t num) {
    if (num) {
        print_num(num / 10);
        cout << num % 10;
    }
}
```

Попробовать на [Ideone](http://ideone.com/RMe4Zd)

Comment: действительно, элегантно)

Comment: Только вот 0 не напечатает (хотя, 0 это и не натуральное число).

Comment: @avp напечатает

Comment: А что есть uint32_t? int не прокатит?

Comment: @inferus-vv прокатит. Про типы можно вот здесь поглядеть http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstdint

Comment: >А что есть uint32_t? int не прокатит?

почему же, прокатит. Однако использование uint32_t - это попытка привнести определенность в диапазон значений, которую int не гарантирует

Comment: Спасибо большое, очень попомгли :)

Comment: @nanotexnik, 

    @avp напечатает

А если подумать? (в конце-концов просто сами проверьте).

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
void PrintNum(unsigned int num)
{         
    /* не стал заморачиваться с конвертацией int => string, 
       поэтому взял библиотечную из С++11
    */        
    string str = std::to_string(num);
    cout << str[0];

    int length = str.length();

    if(length == 1)
    {            
        cout << endl;
        return;
    }

   num = num % (int)pow(10, length - 1);

   PrintNum(num);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void print_num(int32_t n){
    if (n < 0) {
        cout << "-";
        n = -n;
    }
    if (n > 9) {
        print_num(n / 10);
    }
    cout << n % 10;
}
```

Comment: Для `INT_MIN` не будет работать.

Недавно обсуждали [тут](http://hashcode.ru/questions/304371).

--

Собственно, недаром в задаче к вопросу озвучены натуральные числа.

Comment: если уж совсем лезть в ... то это упражнение из K&R в котором отдельно расматривают случай signed min int  там же где и atoi

Comment: @qulinxao, чем больше народу будет хоть что-то слышать об `INT_MIN == -INT_MIN`, тем меньше будет глюков в рабочих программах.

Comment: стоит помнить о краеугольном правиле Unix-программирования 

лучше 80% сейчас , чем 100% когда нибудь в будущем.

Comment: Тем более, что ошибка (при случайном выборе числа) произойдет примерно 1 раз на 4294967295 вызовов

(значительно реже рекомндованных 1 из 5).

--

Впрочем, данный случай это скорее вопрос принципа, а не, скажем, применимости хэш-таблиц в управлении светофорами.